# In woocommerce (for wordpress) I would like to users to pay using coupons as payment option. What is the best way to go around it?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce (for wordpress) I would like to users to pay using coupons as payment option. What is the best way to go around it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-auto-added-coupons/

plugin to achive this goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved me